# Get OpenGl running in a Nativescript Angular application

Tags: nativescript

I'm currently trying to get an Angular-Nativescript-OpenGl-App runnning. See: https://github.com/Franziskus1988/nativescript-opengl.

Unfortunately it only works when I use native Java for the OpenGL rendering part (GLSurfaceView.Renderer).

Can somebody help me to get this running in "plain" NativeScript.

Comment: By "not working" I mean the rendering area remains black.

Comment: What really bothers me is the fact that I don't get any usable information on WHY it isn't working. No expection thrown, no error log, `glGetError()` returns 0....

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know there is a [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/289), register your vote on the issue and hopefully they will pick it up soon when more people show interest towards the feature.

Comment: I know, but this request is open since june 2015, so I don't expect any progress.